# ruby:No such file or directory--script/generate(Load error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I typed code"ruby script/generate model as name:string description:text price:decimal seller_id:integer email:string img_url:string"in"rail_apps".but the cmd shows the error like what the title shows.You can know more refering to the Chap2 of the book"[深入浅出.Ruby.on.Rails].OReilly.Head.First.Rails.Jan.A.learner's.companion.to.Ruby.on.Rails.2009"I am looking forward your help.Thankyou~

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 3, you need to use `rails generate ...` instead of `./script/generate ...` (or `ruby script/generate ...`).

Likewise, `script/console` is now `rails console` (or `rails c` for short) and `script/server` is `rails server` (or `rails s` for short).

Comment: Thanks~The rails I use is the instant rails,but it seems that it can identify the codes like "script/generate.."and so on..

Comment: I met another problem just now.I typed "cd generate"and then "rake db:migrate"but the CMD shows that "rake aborted could not open database" can ya figure out why..I am really sorry to trouble you coz I am such a rookie..